# Perform bitwise operation on particular columns of a Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with a column containing values like `3468936084` (Long). The result I want after performing bitwise operations is:

```
((3468936084) >> 16 & 255) = 195
```

I tried this:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("second", col("aNumber")>> 16 & 255)
```

But it is not working.

How can I get the expected result in scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a `udf` to perform bitwise operation as shown below:

```
scala> val input = Seq((1, 3468936084L),(2,1468936085L)).toDF("id","num")
input: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, num: bigint]

scala> input.show
+---+----------+
| id|       num|
+---+----------+
|  1|3468936084|
|  2|1468936085|
+---+----------+


scala> val myUdf = udf((number: Long) => (number) >> 16 & 255)
myUdf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,LongType,Some(List(LongType)))

scala> input.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- num: long (nullable = false)


scala> val df1 = input.withColumn("bitwise", myUdf(col("num")))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, num: bigint ... 1 more field]

scala> df1.show
+---+----------+-------+
| id|       num|bitwise|
+---+----------+-------+
|  1|3468936084|    195|
|  2|1468936085|    142|
+---+----------+-------+
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Answer (score 2):

```
val df = Seq("3468936084").toDF("A")
val bitOpearationUDF=(value:String) => value.toLong >> 16 & 255
val bitOperation = udf(bitOpearationUDF)
df.withColumn("NewColum", bitOperation(df("A")))
```

try above code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`shiftright`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#shiftright) + [`&`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#_3) functions within SQL `expr`:

```
val df = Seq((3468936084L)).toDF("aNumber")

df.withColumn("second", expr("shiftright(aNumber, 16) & 255")).show

//+----------+------+
//|   aNumber|second|
//+----------+------+
//|3468936084|   195|
//+----------+------+
```